# Show duplicate values in R shiny plot when selectizeInput = TRUE

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm having difficulty trying to figure out how to show all the values in my ggplot in my shiny app. There are some instances inside my data frame where I have some sites having the same value for the same date. When I try to select all them in the app and show them in the plot, they aren't showing up. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but can't seem to find any solutions. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

**Sample Data:**

```
df<-structure(list(`AQS Code` = c(340071001, 340170006, 340010006, 
340070002, 340273001, 340150002, 340290006, 340410007, 340190001, 
340030006, 340110007, 340250005, 340130003, 340315001, 340210005, 
340230011, 340219991, 340071001, 340170006, 340010006), Latitude = c("39.684249999999999", 
"40.670250000000003", "39.464872", "39.934446000000001", "40.787627999999998", 
"39.800339000000001", "40.064830000000001", "40.924579999999999", 
"40.515262", "40.870435999999998", "39.422272999999997", "40.277647000000002", 
"40.720989000000003", "41.058616999999998", "40.283092000000003", 
"40.462181999999999", "40.3125", "39.684249999999999", "40.670250000000003", 
"39.464872"), State = c("NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
"NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
"NJ", "NJ"), `Site Name` = c("Ancora State Hospital", "Bayonne", 
"Brigantine", "Camden Spruce St", "Chester", "Clarksboro", "Colliers Mills", 
"Columbia", "Flemington", "Leonia", "Millville", "Monmouth University", 
"Newark Firehouse", "Ramapo", "Rider University", "Rutgers University", 
"Washington Crossing", "Ancora State Hospital", "Bayonne", "Brigantine"
), `Elev (m)` = c("33.0", "3.0", "5.0", "4.0", "278.0", "12.0", 
"41.0", "146.0", "45.0", "1.0", "22.0", "8.0", "27.0", "307.0", 
"30.0", "19.0", "61.0", "33.0", "3.0", "5.0"), County = c("Camden, NJ", 
"Hudson, NJ", "Atlantic, NJ", "Camden, NJ", "Morris, NJ", "Gloucester, NJ", 
"Ocean, NJ", "Warren, NJ", "Hunterdon, NJ", "Bergen, NJ", "Cumberland, NJ", 
"Monmouth, NJ", "Essex, NJ", "Passaic, NJ", "Mercer, NJ", "Middlesex, NJ", 
"Mercer, NJ", "Camden, NJ", "Hudson, NJ", "Atlantic, NJ"), Date = structure(c(17956, 
17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 
17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17957, 17957, 
17957), class = "Date"), AQI_value = c(36, 30, 36, 32, 34, 30, 
40, 26, 27, 31, 38, 44, 28, 35, 36, 35, 35, 31, 34, 34)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

**Sample App:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(selectizeInput("site_name_select",
                                "Choose Site:",choices = df$`Site Name`,
                                multiple = TRUE,options = list(
                                  placeholder = "Please select a site below"
                                )),
  dateRangeInput("dates","Choose Date Range:",
                 start = "2019-03-01",
                 end = "2019-03-02"),
  plotOutput("plot1")))


server <- function(input, output) { 

  df_reac<-reactive({
    req(input$site_name_select)
    req(input$dates)
    df%>%
      filter(`Site Name` ==input$site_name_select,
             between(Date ,input$dates[1], input$dates[2]))
  })

  output$plot1<-renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df_reac(),aes(x=Date,y=AQI_value,
                                  color = df_reac()$`Site Name`))+
      geom_point(size = 3.5)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: My initial guess is that since you allow for multiple selections, that you need to change your filter. Right now, filter compares `Site Name` with 1 value of `input$site_name_select`, though this input may contain multiple values. Try changing to: `filter(Site Name %in% input$site_name_select`